# To unify the linespacing inside alignat and outside

Tags: line-spacing

I have a code like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\parindent = 0 pt 
\linespread{2.9} %set it very big to emphasize the problem
\begin{document}
$12345678910$\\
\fbox{$\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}d_{l^2}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z})&=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2+\cdots+(x_n-y_n)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1+y_1-z_1)^2+(x_2-y_2+y_2-z_2)^2+\cdots+(x_n-y_n+y_n-z_n)^2}
\end{alignedat}$}\\
Let $\mathbf{u}=(x_1-y_1,x_2-y_2,\cdots,x_n-y_n),~\mathbf{v}=(y_1-z_1,y_2-z_2,\cdots,y_n-z_n)$.\\
Then $\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}&=\lVert\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}\rVert_2\overset{\star}{\leq} \lVert\mathbf{u}\rVert_2+\lVert\mathbf{v}\rVert_2\\
&=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2+\cdots+(x_n-y_n)^2}+\sqrt{(y_1-z_1)^2+(y_2-z_2)^2+\cdots+(y_n-z_n)^2}\\
&=d_{l^2}(x,y)+d_{l^2}(y,z)
\end{alignedat}$\\
Test Words. Test Words.\\
Test Words. Test Words.\\
Test Words. Test Words.\\
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

**Q1.** Is the linespacing in `alignedat` exactly the same as the normal text? Well, it looks like so, but I'm not pretty sure.

**Q2.** As you can see, not every line has the same spacing. What is the linespace in red place controlled by? I think it has nothing to do with `fboxsep`, since if I remove the `\fbox`, the space is still there. How can I change it to be consistent to the others? How can I unify the linespacing inside `alignat` and outside?